# Content type that calls in 5 nodes

Tags: nodes

I have 3 content types

First is `contest`
Second is `contest_applicants`
Third is `contest_results`

People will submit `contest_applicants` for a `contest` (with references modules i assume)

When making the `contest_results` content, I need to be able to select specific `contest_applicants`to display in the results. Kinda like nesting the nodes.

I been looking for a module that does something like this hut, had no success.

I would uses views but, it needs to be a content type since it will be multiple `contest_results`

Is there any module I can use to achieve the above setup? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [field_collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) and [entityreference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.